# wp simple membership plugin simultaneously login

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm using the WP Simple Membership plugin for my Wordpress website.
I use 2 "users" to protect 2 sections from the public. Who ever has the login for one of those 2 sections may login, and see the restricted content.

However, when 1 person is logged in to view "section1", someone else can't login for that same section! This is crucial since people all over the world should have access for those 2 sections.

**How can I achieve that the simultaneously login for one "user" is allowed?**

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: have you assigned particular user to the section?

Comment: There are only 2 "users": section1 & section2. I use that to login to the restricted pages. So everyone who may see that content, gets the login, so in fact there are only 2 "users".

Comment: i mean have you assign users such in a way that only user1 can see section 1 and user2 can see section2?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 sections: "Partner" and "Investor".  Person X who logs in with partner, will only see the partner page.